# Swashbuckle document an enum as an integer

Tags: asp.net, enums, swashbuckle

All of our enums, except one, are serialized as a string.  The one exception is required to be an integer (0, 1, 2, 3) based on a vendor contract.

We have this working properly in the implementation by defining the default converter and overriding the one property:

```
options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
```

and the attribute above the property:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(SerializePropertyAsDefaultConverter<EnumIntegerType>))]
```

However, Swashbuckle's generated documentation records this as a string type with string parameters:

```
EnumIntegerType:
  enum:
    - value0
    - value1
    - value2
    - value3
  type: string
```

I tried to override this with MapType and was able to change the type from "string" to "integer" but the enum values were not changed.

Does anyone know how to make Swashbuckle recognize the property has a different json converter?